# Does Samsung profile sharing work on other Android devices?

Tags: samsung, contacts

The Contacts app on Samsung Android phones has a feature called [profile sharing](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/what-is-profile-sharing/). If you enable it, it lets you share your name, phone number and profile picture with all your contacts. Your contacts will now be able to see your profile picture in their Contacts app, presumably, similarly to WhatsApp or Signal.

Does this feature in Samsung Contacts app work on other phones? Is there a way to get it to work on other phones? Do other brands have similar functionality?